# Calling task chunk with keyword arguments

Tags: python, celery, celery-task, keyword-argument, celery-canvas

How do I chunk tasks with keyword arguments? For example, this task:

```
@app.task
def add(x, y, multiply=1, unit="GB"):
    return '%s %s' % ((x + y) * multiply, unit)
```

I can call this task as usual with `add.apply_async(args=(1, 2), kwargs={'unit': 'MB'})` but how do I chunk it?

I want to do something like :

```
add.chunks([{'args': (1, 2), 'kwargs': {'unit': 'MB'}}, {'args': (3, 4), 'kwargs': {'unit': 'KB'}}, ...], 10)
```

The [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chunks%20documentation) only shows how to use chunks with positional arguments:

```
from proj.tasks import add
res = add.chunks(zip(range(100), range(100)), 10)()
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I see in [`chunks` source code](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/canvas.html#chunks) you have to give an iterable of tuple of arguments.

So you can make this kind of helper :

```
def build_kwargs_tuples(params, default_multiply=1, default_unit="GB"):
    for d in params:
        x,y = d["args"]
        kwargs = d.get("kwargs",{})
        multiply = kwargs.get("multiply", default_multiply)
        unit = kwargs.get("unit", default_unit)
        yield (x,y,multiply, unit)
```

Then you can specify your arguments the way you ask :

```
In [40]: example = [{'args': (1, 2), "kwargs": {'unit': 'MB'}}, {'args': (3, 4), "kwargs": {'unit': 'KB'}}]

In [41]: res = add.chunks(build_kwargs_tuples(example),1)()

In [43]: res.get()
Out[43]: [[u'3 MB'], [u'7 KB']]
```

Comment: This only uses positional arguments, not keyword arguments

Comment: In the definition of my task,  there are only keyword arguments (like in yours). It's only when I call the task that I use their position. Maybe I did not understand what you wanted to achieve, in this case please post a piece of code and the desired behavior

Comment: How you would like to chunk the tasks ?  how your arguments should vary ? I mean do you want to apply this task with `x in range(100)` `y in range(100)`  and fixed `unit = "GB" `?

Comment: I want to do something like `add.chunks([{'args': (1, 2), kwargs: {'unit': 'MB'}}, {'args': (3, 4), kwargs: {'unit': 'KB'}}, ...], 10)`